# jQuery's on click function working inconsistently

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have the following code:

```
<td colspan="10" id="letters">
   <span class="letter">A</span>
   <span class="letter">B</span>
   <span class="letter">C</span>
   <span class="letter">D</span>
</td>
```

With the following jQuery:

```
$(".letter").on("click", function () {
    alert("test");
});
```

It does not work. Clicking the `<span>` doesn't trigger the function within Firefox's debugger. When I other finders, such as:

```
$("#letters .letter").on("click", function () {...
```

..it also does not work. I have noticed this inconsistency with jQuery. On some elements within my page I can use the `(class).on("click")` function without issue, but with others it does not work.

Comment: Here's some information about [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

Comment: Have you checked whether there's a syntax error somewhere in your code preventing the event handler from being created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your span has been added dynamically, try to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** here:

```
$('body').on('click', '.letter', function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

Comment: This fixed it, thankyou. Will select as answer after allotted times has passed.

Answer (score -1):

Try to bind event on `parent` instead of `child`.

```
$('#letters').on("click", function () {
    alert("test");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koushikKumar/Lg83M/28/)

**Event Delegation :**

Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

```
$(document).on('click','.letter',function(){ alert("working");});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("span").click(function(){
        alert("test");
    });
});
```